# Predicate with multiple return values

Tags: c#, return, predicate

I am working on a homework assignment and my teacher has asked this question that I cannot figure out how to answer:

Write a Lambda Expression, using the Predicate delegate, with a double as a
     parameter and returning a bool, double and string as values, you CANNOT use Tuples.

The only way I know to "return multiple values" in C# is by either using Tuples, which I can't do here or by using the out parameter.  I tried to create a predicate with an out parameter and either the syntax is wrong or I just have to do it a different way.  Here's my attempt for a reference.

```
public static void Main()
    {
        double outDouble = 1.0;
        string outString = "string";
        Predicate<double, out double, out string> pred = 
            (double dVal, out double outDouble, out string outString) => 
        {
            if (dVal <= 1.0)
            {
                outDouble = 1.0;
                outString = "string";
                return true;
            }
          else 
            {
                outDouble = 0.0;
                outString = "";
                return false;
            }
        };
        bool predBool = pred(2.0, out outDouble, out outString);
        WriteLine(predBool);
        ReadKey(true);
    }
```

Please help finding an answer to this question. :)

Comment: Are you similarly forbidden from returning a struct or a class instance?

Comment: Have you tried using a callback (`Action<T1, T2, T3, T4>`)? Then in the calling code, you can write a lambda expression to read the values out from the callback?

Comment: Either the question was poorly written or you've misunderstood something - The [`Predicate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate takes a single object and returns a bool.  Unless your teacher counts mutating the properties of the input object "returning"  values I don't see how it's possible.

Comment: Yeah I'm forbidden from structs and classes too

Comment: Can you give an example of the Action callback? I have another question that it might help with as well that looks like this: Write a Action<T> delegate declaration that can accept the following
method and returns a bool, double, string and int. Stuff is class Stuff( ){ }. You CAN-NOT use a Tuple<T> or other object as the return data-type.

Stuff FooBar(int x, double y, Stuff s){  //code body }

Comment: With the context of that question, it sounds like the callback is what the teacher's getting at, but I think it's very misleading of them to call it "returning". An action with a callback would be like `Action<int, string, Action<bool, double, string>>`. The outside action calls the inner one with the "return" values when it's done.

Comment: So if anyone could answer with an example of how the callback should look that would be great. :)

Comment: @31eee384 To do that you no longer have a `Predicate` delegate.

Comment: @Servy Ah, yeah. I guess "return" includes "mutate closed-on variables" then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mutate the variables within the lambda by closing over them, rather than by explicitly passing them as a parameter or as the return value.

```
double outDouble = 1.0;
string outString = "string";
Predicate<double> pred = dVal => 
{
    if (dVal <= 1.0)
    {
        outDouble = 1.0;
        outString = "string";
        return true;
    }
  else 
    {
        outDouble = 0.0;
        outString = "";
        return false;
    }
};
bool predBool = pred(2.0);
WriteLine(predBool);
ReadKey(true);
```